# Find location or near by location in PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip-geolocation

Hey guys I was wondering if there is a script that allows me to find a pretty accurate or near by location of a user using PHP.

I needed this to be implement in my code so wanted to see if anyone know a good solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "pretty accurate". With PHP, you can only do IP adress based geolocation. This will tell you pretty accurately what country your visitors are from. I have often experienced that the "city" information from IP geolocation had an error of 200km or more...

Comment: More precise information can be acquired via JavaScript in some Browsers (Chrome, Safari). The Browser will use nearby wifi networks to find the current location. However, the browser will ask for confirmation before allowing to retrieve the users location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all read about [PHP GeoIP](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php). As data source you can use [maxmind.com](http://www.maxmind.com/) databases. For instance [GeoLite City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) (it's free).

Comment: Yes that MaxMind database looks very promising. I think I might end up buying their paid version. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
/*---------------------Distance specification----------------*/

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) { 

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * 
    cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {

    return ($miles * 1.609344); 

  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
        return $miles;
  }
}



/*---------------------Distance specification----------------*/


/*-------------Radius check starts-------------------------*/

class RadiusCheck {

var $maxLat;
var $minLat;
var $maxLong;
var $minLong;

function RadiusCheck($Latitude, $Longitude, $Miles) {
global $maxLat,$minLat,$maxLong,$minLong;
$EQUATOR_LAT_MILE = 69.172;
$maxLat = $Latitude + $Miles / $EQUATOR_LAT_MILE;
$minLat = $Latitude - ($maxLat - $Latitude);
$maxLong = $Longitude + $Miles / (cos($minLat * M_PI / 180) * $EQUATOR_LAT_MILE);
$minLong = $Longitude - ($maxLong - $Longitude);
}

function MaxLatitude() {
return $GLOBALS["maxLat"];
}
function MinLatitude() {
return $GLOBALS["minLat"];
}
function MaxLongitude() {
return $GLOBALS["maxLong"];
}
function MinLongitude() {
return $GLOBALS["minLong"];
}

}


/*-------------Radius check ends---------------------------*/


/*-------------Distance check starts-----------------------*/
class DistanceCheck {

function DistanceCheck() {
}

function Calculate(
$dblLat1,
$dblLong1,
$dblLat2,
$dblLong2
) {
$EARTH_RADIUS_MILES = 3963;
$dist = 0;

//convert degrees to radians
$dblLat1 = $dblLat1 * M_PI / 180;
$dblLong1 = $dblLong1 * M_PI / 180;
$dblLat2 = $dblLat2 * M_PI / 180;
$dblLong2 = $dblLong2 * M_PI / 180;

if ($dblLat1 != $dblLat2 || $dblLong1 != $dblLong2)
{
//the two points are not the same
$dist =
sin($dblLat1) * sin($dblLat2)
+ cos($dblLat1) * cos($dblLat2)
* cos($dblLong2 - $dblLong1);

$dist =
$EARTH_RADIUS_MILES
* (-1 * atan($dist / sqrt(1 - $dist * $dist)) + M_PI / 2);
}
return $dist;
}

}


/*-------------Distance check ends--------------------------*/


/*-------------Listing datas starts--------------------------*/

// set a default number of miles to search within
$Miles = '113';

// set the user's latitude and longitude as the one to search against
$Latitude = $getip->latitude;
$Longitude = $getip->latitude;

$zcdRadius = new RadiusCheck($Latitude,$Longitude,$Miles);
$minLat = $zcdRadius->MinLatitude();
$maxLat = $zcdRadius->MaxLatitude();
$minLong = $zcdRadius->MinLongitude();
$maxLong = $zcdRadius->MaxLongitude();

$sql = "SELECT Latitude,Longitude,TimeZone,DmaId,County,Code,ctyvalue,ctstatus, ";

$sql .= "SQRT((((69.1*(Latitude-$Latitude))*(69.1*(Latitude-$Latitude)))+((53*(Longitude-$Longitude))*(53*(Longitude-$Longitude))))) ";
$sql .= "AS calc FROM geo_cities where  ";
$sql .= "latitude >= '$minLat' ";
$sql .= "AND Latitude <= '$maxLat' ";
$sql .= "AND Longitude >= '$minLong' ";
$sql .= "AND Longitude <= '$maxLong' ";

//echo $sql;

$get_data = mysql_query($sql);

// loop through the matching database results
while($storedata = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {

// calculate the number of miles away the result is
$zcdDistance = new DistanceCheck;
$Distance = $zcdDistance->Calculate($Latitude,$Longitude,$storedata['latitude'],$storedata['longitude']);

// and for the non-US people, here's the km calculation
$calc_km = round(($Distance * 1.609344),2);

//echo distance($Latitude,$Longitude,$storedata['latitude'],$storedata['longitude'], "m") . " miles";


echo '<li>'.$storedata['ctyname'].'<br />'.$storedata['County'].', ';
echo 'Distance: '.$Distance.' ('.$calc_km.' km)';
}





/*-------------Listing datas ends----------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the maxmind system, there's also [ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php). However IME, I wouldn't expect an average accuracy of better than 300 miles.

HTML5 provides a [javascript API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to determine location on the client by various methods. Where available, this is much more accurate - but it does result in a prompt to the user to permit capture of the data - and if you've no GPS / Wifi connectivity, it will just timeout.